# How to get data from mysql database only for this year

Tags: php, mysql, date

Inside my table "news" there is "date_in" field storing date when some news has been created in this format "20150108";

I need to get news that are made in the current year.

```
select title, text from news where date_in = ?
```

How can I do this using php/mysql ?

Thanks

Comment: first, make the column data type as `DATE` then use the `YEAR()` mysql function

Comment: what is datatype for date_in field.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).  Your question is fairly broad and depends on many database settings which only you would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the year as below from the given format.

```
mysql> select year('20150108');
+------------------+
| year('20150108') |
+------------------+
|             2015 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in the query you can have

```
select 
title, 
text 
from news 
where year(date_in) = year(curdate());
```

Comment: One question: What if I want to select only news from last 12 months instead of this year ? Because at 01.01.2016 I will not have anything.

Comment: You can have the where condition as `where date(date_in) between date_sub(curdate() ,interval 12 month) and curdate()`

Answer (score 1):

It will help you [**Documentation Here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/year.html)

```
SELECT  title, text FROM  news WHERE  YEAR(date_in) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

It will help you

```
select title, text from news where  YEAR(date_in) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use `year()`:

```
select title, text
from news
where year(date_in) = year(now());
```

A better way is to avoid using a function on the current date.  Assuming you have no future dates:

```
select title, text
from news
where date_in >= makedate(year(now(), 1);
```

This version is better because the query can take advantage of an index on `date_in`.

Answer (score 0):

try using substring to filter out the year IF the date_in column is of type nvarchar,varchar etc:

```
SELECT title, text 
FROM news 
WHERE date_in = SUBSTRING(date_in, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, $CurrentYear=date('Y'); //Current Year i.e. 2015
Then, SELECT title, text FROM news WHERE date_in LIKE '%$CurrentYear%'

Answer (score 0):

select title, text from news where date_in > 20150101

or $query = 'select title, text from news where date_in > ' . date("Y") . '0101';